# retornar lista json asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

necesito saber el método para retornar una lista con el fin de optimizar la extracción de datos de la base para luego mostrarla en una tabla, estoy con ASP.NET MVC 5.
por medio de un botón debería de cargar los datos en la tabla, traté de cargarlos ni bien se abría la view pero eran muchas consultas.

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#btnMostrarDato").click(function() {
                var url1 = "@Url.Action("MostrarDato1","Censos")";
                $.post(url1, data1).done(function(data1) { $("#vivienda1").html(data1); })
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

el controller..

```
public JsonResult MostrarDato1()
        {
            var vivienda1= (from item in _context.Censo where item.Caps == "Hogar" && item.TipoVivienda == "Casilla" select item.TipoVivienda).Count();
            return Json(vivienda1);
        }
```

esta parte es de la tabla, donde se ve como se muestran los datos y el botón

```
<td><span id="vivienda1"></span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="MostrarDato" id="btnMostrarDato" />
```

se puede usar el JsonResult para retornar una lista?

Comment: Respuesta: Sí, sí se puede usar JsonResult para retornar una vista. Una pregunta, eso no estaba claro en la documentación oficial? Otra pregunta, quzás más importante, a qué te refieres con *traté de cargarlos ni bien se abría la view pero eran muchas consultas*? No suena a algo que el framework haga regularmente.

Comment: Hola Ariel, me refería en el método index, hacia una consulta usando linq y lo retornaba con un viewbag.